# How may I see calendar all-day reminders on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, calendar

Like many people, I use *Calendar* on both my Mac and iPhone and sync events between both devices.

I use **all-day** events on the Mac extensively; but I am frustrated that I can not see the same all-day events on my iPhone. I am restricted to setting an alert on the event and relying on being able to address the event at the time of the alert.

I would much rather be able **to see the list of all-day events on my iPhone as well as the Mac.**

**Is there any way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What view are you using?

If you turn the phone sideways it will flip from the standard 'month with dots & details of today' view into week view, where all-day events are at the top of each day.
It doesn't show them as a list; you can only do that with the Today view, which lists everything.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Honestly. It was as simple as turning the phone to landscape orientation.I search the Web for this… and nothing.
I should add that the "Today" view does NOT list all-day events on my iPhone.
But the landscape view works. I had forgotten that it switches to the week view; so thanks again for that.
All the best.

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone I use Calendar widget on homescreen and there is list display of all-day events (I created three dummy all-day test events):

[image]

On Mac in Notification Center this is displayed as follows:

[image]